# How can I increase a scoreboard objective if player is at specific coords and has a specific item in his inventory?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I don't know how to put those two conditions together into one command. I tried

```
/scoreboard players add @a{Inventory:[{id:"minecraft:iron_ingot"}]} [x=-506,y=56,z=-1176,r=1] Score 1
```

but it doesn't work, and I have trouble with brackets.

Comment: @MrLemon I removed the comment and added it as an answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your whole command is invalid.
The correct format would be

```
/scoreboard players add <player> <objective> <count> [dataTag]
```

so your command would then become:

```
/scoreboard players add @a[x=-506,y=56,z=-1176,r=1] Score 1 {Inventory:[{id:"minecraft:iron_ingot"}]}
```

**Always remember: NBT data tags always come last in a command.**